# How to properly append json result to a select option

Tags: json, jquery

How to properly append json result to a select option,

sample json data

[image]

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'sessions.php',
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: { from: $('#datepicker_from').val().trim(), to: $('#datepicker_to').val().trim() },
        sucess: function(data){
            var toAppend = '';
            //if(typeof data === 'object'){
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    toAppend += '<option>'+data[i]['id']+'</option>';
                }
            //}
            $('#sessions').append(toAppend);
        }
    });
```

html code:

```
<p>Sessions: 
<select id="sessions"></select>
```

I already set to my php file

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use **<kbd>[$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)</kbd>** to iterate through your JSON array that you receive from ajax call.

Note:- the spelling of `success`, you have written `sucess`.

```
 success: function(data){
            var toAppend = '';
           $.each(data,function(i,o){
           toAppend += '<option>'+o.id+'</option>';
          });

         $('#sessions').append(toAppend);
        }
```

You can do append to the DOM directly inside the each loop but it is always better to concatenate with string and then adding to the DOM later. ***This is a cheaper operation since you are accessing DOM only once in this case***. This might not work in some complex scenarios though.

Comment: any errors? Is it not going to the loop or not appending to the Select option?

Answer (score 3):

```
success: function(data) {
     var options = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         options += "<option>" + data[i].id + "</option>";
     }
     $("#sessions").html(options);
 }
```

If your response is in multidimensional array then try as follows

```
success: function(data) {
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j< data[i].length; j++){
            options += '<option value="' + data[i][j].product_id + '">' + data[i][j].name + '</option>';
        }
    }
    $("#products").html(options);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you to append

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    $('#sessions').append("<option value="+data[i].id+"/option>");                      
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let You receive json data in parameter `data`

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    $('#sessions').append("<option value="+obj[i].id+">"+obj[i].name+"</option>");                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code this may help you.

these code i used in spring boot MVC

JSON Data

```
[{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"af"},
{"name":"Albania","code":"al"},
{"name":"Algeria","code":"dz"}]
```

JQuery Code

```
var jsonData = '${restData}';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
for (i in obj) {
$('#selectList').append(new Option(obj[i].name, obj[i].code));
}
```