# How to fetch and manipulate json data using jquery and display in html

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have this JSON data:

```
[{
  "in_id": "1", 
  "in_name": "Education Point",
  "in_email": "",
  "in_pin": "834006"
}, {
  "in_id": "2",
  "in_name": "Vidya Coaching Center",
  "in_email": "",
  "in_pin": "834006"
}]
```

I want to show it inside a `select` tag. I am trying like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: "<?=base_url()?>affiliates/get_institute/" + pin_code,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var html = '';
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      html += "<option value='" + data[i].in_name + "'>" + data[i].in_name + "</option>";
    }
    $('select[name="sel_inst"]').append(html);
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly append json result to a select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160619/how-to-properly-append-json-result-to-a-select-option)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your JS logic seems fine. Does the request fail? Does the `select[name="sel_inst"]` element exist?

Comment: `<select name="sel_inst" id="sel_inst" ></select>`

Answer (score 1):

You need add `<select name="sel_inst"></select>` in your HTML.

You should set `in_id` for value of option instead of `in_name`

I tried to reproduce, it worked

```js
var data = [{"in_id":"1","in_name":"Education Point","in_email":"","in_pin":"834006"},{"in_id":"2","in_name":"Vidya Coaching Center","in_email":"","in_pin":"834006"}];
var html = '';
                  var i;
                  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                      html +="<option value='" +data[i].in_id+"'>"+data[i].in_name+"</option>";
                    }
                  $( 'select[name="sel_inst"]').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel_inst"></select>
```

Comment: but i am not getting it, can you help me more

Comment: Can you post content of data by console.log(data) ?

Comment: Please copy content of console log data here to investigate why

Comment: getting in console but not in the page...everything is right

Comment: <option value='1'>Education Point</option><option value='2'>Vidya Coaching Center</option>

Comment: Do you have select tag with name? Is there any error in console? Please post your html to question too

Comment: Do you have <select name="sel_inst"></select> in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Like Hien Nguyen said, You need add the select tag in your HTML.

and You should set in_id for value of option instead of in_name

also use sel_inst as id, I decided to use a foreach instead and it worked

Hope it helps

```js
let data = [{
  "in_id": "1", 
  "in_name": "Education Point",
  "in_email": "",
  "in_pin": "834006"
}, {
  "in_id": "2",
  "in_name": "Vidya Coaching Center",
  "in_email": "",
  "in_pin": "834006"
}];

let selectBox = $('#sel_inst');
$.each(data,function(index,item){
$(selectBox).append('<option value="'+item.in_id+'" data-pin="'+item.in_pin+'">'+item.in_name+'</option>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select name="sel_inst" id="sel_inst">

</select>
```